# Devexpress TextEdit hiding default datetime values

Tags: datetime, format, devexpress, textedit

I want to hide the default `DateTime` value (`01/01/0001`) if passed to a DevExpress `TextEdit`.

What is the correct way to do this ?
I tried to use masks / Repository items, unsuccessfully.

Thanks in advance for your replies !

Comment: I dont really understand what you want to do. Why you pass a DateTime value to a textedit if you dont want to show it? Else you maybe can hook up the validate event and check that the value of the textedit is not 01/01/0001.

Comment: +1 for @Sebi comment. Also why you are using the TextEdit for a DateTime? Use the [DateEdit](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraEditorsDateEdittopic) for this purpose.

Comment: I use ReadOnly TextEdits for showing the results of an algorithm. I got it. @Sebi comment gave me an idea of how to do it. Handling the `EditValueChanged` event will solve the issue.